# Check if any columns changed in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table that consists of 30 columns.  In another table I have a list of the columns for that table.  Some have an indicator as 0 and others with 1.

I need to that that tables of columns were the indicator = 1 and find out if that column updated during a trigger or not. 
I need this to be simple and with the least amount of code to implement

Can I use columns_updated? or Updated?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Contrary to popular usage, SO is not a free code-writing service. So try doing something. When you encounter a problem, then you post a question about resolving that specific problem. Writing triggers is an advanced skill that requires mastery of basic tsql.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `UPDATE` function?

```
create trigger PersonUpdateTrigger on Person for update as
begin
  if UPDATE(Notes) 
    begin
      -- The Notes field was set in the UPDATE command
    end 
end
```